# Link directly to the first post in an archive

Tags: tags

on my WordPress site, I'm developing a glossary list of novel writing terms, using tags and tags descriptions to draw definitions from. Currently, when any tag has more than 0 posts associated with it, it will link to that tag's archive page, allowing readers to further read up on the topic.

What I would like to achieve, is to have any tag that has exactly 1 post associated with it, to link directly to that post rather than the tag archive. I've been looking around for a solution, but can't seem to find any way to achieve that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

For reference, this is the current code:

```
<!-- Add glossary list in content -->
<?php foreach ( $groups as $group ): ?>
    <ul>
    <div class="glossary-title-link" id ="section-<?php echo str_replace(' ', '-', strtolower($group['name'])) ?>">
    <h4 id ="<?php echo $group['name'] ?>"><?php echo $group['name'] ?></h4>
    </div>
    <?php foreach ( $group['tags'] as $tag ): ?>
        <li class="glossary-list">

        <!-- If there are any posts for the tag, link to the tag page -->
        <?php

            if ( $tag['count'] > 0 ) {
                echo '<a class="glossary-link" id="term-';
                echo str_replace(' ', '-', strtolower($tag['name']));
                echo '" href="';
                echo $tag['link'];
                echo '">';
                echo $tag['name'];
                echo '</a></br>';


            } else {
                echo '<div class="glossary-link" id="term-';
                echo str_replace(' ', '-', strtolower($tag['name']));
                echo '">';
                echo $tag['name'];
                echo '</div>';

            }
        ?>
        <?php echo $tag['description'] ?></li>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Which leads to this, where 'cliffhangers' is linked and 'denouement' is not:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this ( untested and assuming of course that $tag is the right object tag and  $tag['count'] is the number of post with that tag ):

```
if ( $tag['count'] > 1 ) {
 //first part of your code
}
else if($tag['count'] == 1){
  $the_query = new WP_Query( 'tag='.$tag['name'] );
  if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
      $the_query->the_post();
      echo '<a href="';
      echo get_the_permalink();
      echo '">';
      echo $tag['slug'];
      echo '</a></br>';
    }
  }
  wp_reset_query();
}
else{
//// last part of your code
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to work as intended, with 1-post tags still linking to the full archive, and 0-post tags (i.e. everything covered in the else statement) suddenly disappearing. 

I've updated my original post to include the full code, if that's any use, with the `$group` object tag coming from the [Tag Groups](https://chattymango.com/tag-groups/tag-groups-examples-of-applications/) plugin. The page in its original state can be seen [here](https://nearlycomplete.net/glossary/). Thanks again for your help!

Comment: have a look at the output of `var_dump($tag)` (inside the <li>) to see what are the values of it..

Comment: That's very useful, I wasn't aware you could do that! Here's what I'm getting for an example 1-post tag:

`array(7) { ["term_id"]=> int(152) ["link"]=> string(39) "https://nearlycomplete.net/writing/wip/" ["description"]=> string(86) "Work-in-progress. Any novel you're currently pouring your heart, soul and sanity into." ["count"]=> int(1) ["slug"]=> string(3) "wip" ["name"]=> string(3) "WIP" ["tg_font_size"]=> float(12) }`

Comment: so first of all: `$the_query = new WP_Query( 'tag='.$tag['slug'] );` for the rest $tag['count'] should be ok to compare with since it's an INT..

Comment: That does fix the problem with 0-post tags disappearing, but unfortunately the 1-post tags still link to the archive as before. I've tried to only echo a test string within the `else if($tag['count'] == 1)` statement, and that didn't show up anywhere either. It seems to somehow not compare with the `$tag['count']` properly, even though to the best of my knowledge it should.

Comment: Never mind, I figured out what was wrong! Seems like in undoing some earlier changes I had mistakenly reverted the initial `if ( $tag['count'] > 1 ){` in the first part of the code back to `if ( $tag['count'] > 0 ) {`. Working like a charm now, thank you so much for your help!